Nextcloud android app does not work with the community nextcloud docker image, and caddy as a reverse proxy
I want to setup nextcloud in my home server with the following (in order of importance):

Nextcloud is fast on a web browser and phone
Nextcloud is encrypted with trusted SSL certificates, but without making the server accessable to anyone on the internet (so I use duckDNS as a domain, with caddy as a reverse proxy, and dns 01 challanges)
I can access the server from anywhere in the world (so I use twingate)
The server is as private as possible with as little data going to third parties as possible
(ideally) everything runs using docker compose for easy setup that is reliable

To achieve this, I have tried to setup the community nextcloud docker image with caddy, DNS 01 challanges, and twingate, but I cannot log in with android. When I try to login, I enter the server URL, click trust device, enter my login details, and then there is just a infinite loading spinner with a message saying that http is not supported, even though trusted SSL certs work fine on browsers. How can I setup next cloud with the criteria above? Here is a link to all of my configs: https://github.com/godalming123/server-docker-files Any help is much appreciated.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
